# How to get to Vergen in Witcher 2?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I'm in the underground tunnels, but i don't have the key required to get to Vergen.

Where do I get the keys? I've already got the sword with Saskia.

Here is where I'm stuck:

[image: map]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can't go into Vergen(provided you are playing the Special Forces quest line with Roche), instead you need to procure the spear tip and return to the army camp...